# Linq to SQL doesn't save property named 'Value'

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, insert

I am inserting a `UserStat` record--nothing out of the ordinary so far as I can tell. The basic idea is to iterate a set of values, `Stats`, and create `UserStat` records copying some of the `Stat` data.

However, when I debug, *immediately* after any `userStat.Value = <some number>;` statement, the value of `.Value` is still 0.0. It's a float in the SQL Server database if that matters. *But*, the `.AnotherProperty` and `.SomeOtherProp` fields in the db are also floats--they are saved *perfectly*.

My consistent and reproducible problem is that `.Value` never persists (even in the local instance) when being modified. Maybe this needs a fresh pair of eyes--am I missing something that should be obvious?

```
        using (MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext())
        {
            List<UserStat> stats = new List<UserStat>();

            // create stats
            foreach (var stat in db.Stats)
            {
                UserStat userStat = new UserStat()
                {
                    // set some common properties
                };

                switch (stat.ID)
                {
                    case (int)Enums.Stats.Stat1:
                        userStat.Value = 1;
                        // right here, userStat.Value == 0 is true...HUH?
                        userStat.AnotherProperty = 2;
                        userStat.SomeOtherProp = 5;
                        break;
                    case (int)Enums.Stats.Stat2:
                        userStat.Value = 5;
                        // right here, userStat.Value == 0 is true...HUH?
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }

                stats.Add(userStat);
            }

            db.UserStats.InsertAllOnSubmit(stats);

            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
```

**Update**

Yes, it's my fault. I had a partial class definition on `UserStat` for `OnValueChanged()` that was making a business modification I implemented too long ago to remember as it was the only business modification on that class while others have many I constantly debug.

Comment: Have you directly tested at the comment point that the `value == 0`?   Or are you making that assumption because it doesn't save?

Comment: @smartcaveman: "However, when I debug,..." I've debugged on the statement that follows the line and it is 0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops--I missed a partial class definition that modified UserStat in the `.OnValueChanged()` definition.

Answer (score 0):

`Value` might be a keyword and is causing you some unexpected behavior. Change that column name to something else.

Comment: I thought about that, but 1) modifications to `UserStat` records are fine elsewhere in my project and 2) I debugged with Linq to SQL profiler and it is wrapping the `.Value` column in square brackets appropriately e.g. `INSERT INTO [UserStat] SET [Value]=123...`. Is there some specific behavior you're suggesting is causing this?

Comment: Let me clarify--modifications to UserStat `.Value` work as expected elsewhere. When debugging, the object has nothing to do with its future database counterpart, it's just a public property of an object in the data context.